# How to open a MVC 4 view from javascript in a new popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC view page in which there is a HTML ActionLink and on click of that action link, i want to open a new popup window without closing the previous one. In this new popup window i want to show a MVC view but i am unable to do that.

Now i am using the following codes to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('a.edit').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.showModalDialog(url, "#1", "dialogHeight:600px;dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:700px;dialogTop:300px;dialogLeft:400px;edge:Raised;center:Yes;help:No;Resiable:No;Status:No;");
    });
    return false;
});
```

```
@Html.ActionLink("Answer", "getanswer", new {controller="Question"}, new {target="_blank",@class="edit"})
```

But the problem is that instead of opening as a popup window it is opening in a new tab window. So i an unable to find where i am doing wrong.

And i also tried **window.open** instead of **window.showModalDialog** but i am getting the same result.

So if anybody can find where i am doing wrong or how to solve this problem please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink creates HTML in the DOM:

```
 <a href="question/getanswer" target="_blank" class="edit">Answer</a>
```

Which of course is firing and opening the link in a new tab.

You might be trying to stop this event from happening by returning false but you are not returning false in the right place, currently you return false from the document.ready event completing, you should delete that `return false;`...try:

```
$('a.edit').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.showModalDialog(url, "#1", "dialogHeight:600px;dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:700px;dialogTop:300px;dialogLeft:400px;edge:Raised;center:Yes;help:No;Resiable:No;Status:No;");
        return false;
    });
```

Or and this is better:

```
$('a.edit').click(function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.showModalDialog(url, "#1", "dialogHeight:600px;dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:700px;dialogTop:300px;dialogLeft:400px;edge:Raised;center:Yes;help:No;Resiable:No;Status:No;");
        e.stopPropagation;
    });
```

If the above is not enough to fix the problem, then stop using an `@Html.ActionLink` for now and replace with this:

```
<div href="@Url.Action("getanswer", "Question")" class="edit" style="cursor: pointer">Answer</div>
```

Then change you jQuery selector from `a.edit` to `.edit`

Now, for sure, you will stop the link from opening in a new tab and you can more properly focus and debug the jQuery click binding.

Comment: Hi @Brian Ogden, i have modified as per your information but no changes in output, means no popup window is coming that is opening in a new tab window.

Comment: @Ashish I updated my answer with additional change to your HTML

Comment: Sorry @Brian Ogden, after modifying as per your latest updates as nothing is happening, means neither that is opening in a new popup window nor in a new tab window.

Comment: That shows you that your window.showModalDialog is not working as you expect, you need to start debugging with console.log and seeing that you click event is firing, window.showModalDialog is deprecated and you should be using window.open